# how to compare elements of arrays inside two different objects and display which element belonged to which array that was inside the object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
let buckets = [
  { first: { fname: "David", locations: ["q1,""q2,"q3","q4"] } },
  { second: { fname: "Eric", locations: ["a1","a2","a3","a4"] } },
];

test : ["a1","q2","q4","w100"];
```

Here, the elements inside test can be and any element that is not present in locations needs to be ignored, since `w100` is not present it needs to be ignored

For final output I needed something like below:

Since the first element of test belongs to location from second object, I need to have output as:

```
{
  fname: "Eric",    
  testing: "a1",    
  name: "copying a1"    
},
```

Since the second element of test belongs to location form first object, I need to have output as:

```
{    
  fname: "David",    
  testing: "q2",    
  name: "copying q2"    
}
```

And the same rule for the third element too:

```
{    
  fname: "David",    
  testing: "q4",    
  name: "copying "q4"    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const buckets = [{
    first: {
      fname: "David",
      locations: ["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"]
    }
  },
  {
    second: {
      fname: "Eric",
      locations: ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]
    }
  },
]

const test = ["a1", "q2", "q4", "w100"];

//must take in objects you suspect test values derive from
function compare(obj1, obj2, test) {
  
  //reduce each test ele into an initial empty array output
  const output = test.reduce((arr, test) => {
    //if test ele belongs to first obj
    if (obj1.locations.indexOf(test) > -1) {
      //add the following to output
      arr.push({
        fname: obj1.fname,
        testing: test,
        name: `copying ${test}`
      })
    //if test ele belongs to second obj
    } else if (obj2.locations.indexOf(test) > -1) {
      //add the following to output
      arr.push({
        fname: obj2.fname,
        testing: test,
        name: `copying ${test}`
      })
    }
    //repeat cycle
    return arr;
  }, [])

  return output;

}

//pass in the nested objects, not the root objects
console.log(compare(buckets[0].first, buckets[1].second, test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear to me, but I'll give it a shot:

```js
let buckets = [{
  first: {
    fname: "David",
    locations: ["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"]
  }
}, {
  second: {
    fname: "Eric",
    locations: ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"]
  }
}, ];

const test = ["a1", "q2", "q4", "w100"];

// the "first" and "second" keys are not used for anything
const flatBuckets = buckets.map(e => {
  return Object.values(e)[0]
})

// creating the result:
const result = test.map(e => {
  const c = flatBuckets.find(el => {
    return el.locations.includes(e)
  })
  return c ? {
    fname: c.fname,
    testing: e,
    name: `copying ${ e }`
  } : null
}).filter(e => e)

console.log(result)
```